# SpringData Neo4J Transaction Commit Issue

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Neo4J (3.3.4), SpringData Neo4J (4.2.11.RELEASE) on AWS Linux instance. I am using @Transactional on my service method. When I persist entities it gives me following exception

The interesting part is it is working perfectly fine on windows(with same version of neo4j) while on AWS instance it is not..

Anyone help me out why its happening ?

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: http://<ip_address>:7474/db/data/transaction/2/commit; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionException: http://<ip_address>:7474/db/data/transaction/2/commit
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SessionFactoryUtils.convertOgmAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doCommit(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:265)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy610.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.API..saveProduct(API.java:287)
    at com.API$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1585d098.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.API$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fff3415c.save(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)                           
         Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionException: http://<ip_address>:7474/db/data/transaction/2/commit
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.transaction.HttpTransaction.commit(HttpTransaction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doCommit(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:262)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

## If your datasource is already acceßible

then your problem seems to be from session timeout.
Try to increase the session timeout. From Your tomcat administation console.

And from  neo4j.conf
 on linux    cd /etc/neo4j/

sudo nano neo4j.conf

Try to increase 
dbms.transaction.timeout=(360000 or whatever)

## If your data source is not accessible at all

then do the following

You have to set your datasource   to be reachable
from your ip adress :7474

For example on wildfly this is done inserver\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml

OR from wildfly administrator console(http://localhost:8080) .

Here I show how it's done from

## on server\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/Neo4jDS" pool-name="Neo4jDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:neo4j://YourIpAdress:7474/</connection-url>
                    <driver>neo4j-jdbc-YOURVERSIONHERE-jar-with-dependencies.jar</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE</transaction-isolation>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>youruser</user-name>
                        <password>yourpasswor</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

## If it's already done you have to check if your network on linux

1- cd /etc/network

then apply

2- ifconfig -a

you should have on inet an ip adress matching yours.

inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
if you have other adress ip than yours xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx then

you should update your code java to link this new  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx adress ip.
or re-update as I showed above on standalone.xml.

if the adress on inet match your adress ip 
then check

```
on linux 
cd /etc/neo4j/
sudo nano neo4j.conf
```

and check on the file, you have to see if the right configuration is correct.

```
#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
#dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true

#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
#dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
```

Comment: It is accessible because it successfully saves records. While for some records it is doing the issue i discussed above